# Assert that an array is ordered with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I need to be able to write a test with minitest using ruby that asserts that a given array is ordered by asc or desc.

I have incomplete code as follows:

```
 it "can order an array by asc order" do
     assert_equal tested_array, sorted_array
end
```

Comment: What is your conrete problem, could you provide a code example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your attempt. SO isn't a "give me code" site, it's a "help me fix my code", and your effort is very important. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: @theTinMan I edited the question. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
test "array should be sorted asc" do
  sorted_array = tested_array.sort
  assert_equal tested_array, sorted_array, "Array sorted"
end
```

Same for `desc`, but write `tested_array.sort.reverse` instead `tested_array.sort`